# Drupal 7 not working with drupalvm

Tags: drupal-7

I was trying to create a drupalvm instance running drupal 7 by changing the "core" and "version" as suggested in the readme file, and then running vagrant up, but the issue is that after doing so it keeps on installing drupal8 (default). 
Following are the drupal.make.yml file and the config.yml file that I edited before building the machine.

drupal.make.yml

```
---
api: 2

# Basic Drush Make file for Drupal. Be sure to update the drupal_major_version
# variable inside config.yml if you change the major version in this file.

# Drupal core (major version, e.g. 6.x, 7.x, 8.x).
core: "7.x"

projects:

  # Core.
  drupal:
  type: "core"
  download:
  # Drupal core branch (e.g. "6.x", "7.x", "8.0.x").
  branch: "7.0.x"
  working-copy: true

  # Other modules.
  devel: "1.x-dev"
```

config.yml

```
---
# `vagrant_box` can also be set to geerlingguy/centos6, geerlingguy/centos7,
# geerlingguy/ubuntu1204, parallels/ubuntu-14.04, etc.
vagrant_box: geerlingguy/ubuntu1404
vagrant_user: vagrant
vagrant_synced_folder_default_type: nfs

# If you need to run multiple instances of Drupal VM, set a unique hostname,
# machine name, and IP address for each instance.
vagrant_hostname: drupalvm.dev
vagrant_machine_name: drupalvm
vagrant_ip: 192.168.88.88

# Allow Drupal VM to be accessed via a public network interface on your host.
# Vagrant boxes are insecure by default, so be careful. You've been warned!
# See: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html
vagrant_public_ip: ""

# A list of synced folders, with the keys 'local_path', 'destination', and
# a 'type' of [nfs|rsync|smb] (leave empty for slow native shares). See
# http://docs.drupalvm.com/en/latest/extras/syncing-folders/ for more info.
vagrant_synced_folders:
  # The first synced folder will be used for the default Drupal installation, if
  # build_makefile: is 'true'.
  - local_path: ~/Documents/projectohri/drupalvm
    destination: /var/www/drupalvm
    type: nfs
    create: true

# Memory and CPU to use for this VM.
vagrant_memory: 1024
vagrant_cpus: 2

# The web server software to use. Can be either 'apache' or 'nginx'.
drupalvm_webserver: apache

# Set this to false if you are using a different site deployment strategy and
# would like to configure 'vagrant_synced_folders' and 'apache_vhosts' manually.
build_makefile: true
drush_makefile_path: /vagrant/drupal.make.yml

# Set this to false if you don't need to install drupal (using the drupal_*
# settings below), but instead copy down a database (e.g. using drush sql-sync).
install_site: true

# Settings for building a Drupal site from a makefile (if 'build_makefile:'
# is 'true').
drupal_major_version: 7
drupal_core_path: "/var/www/drupalvm/drupal"
drupal_domain: "drupalvm.dev"
drupal_site_name: "Drupal"
drupal_install_profile: standard
drupal_enable_modules: [ 'devel' ]
drupal_account_name: admin
drupal_account_pass: admin
drupal_mysql_user: drupal
drupal_mysql_password: drupal
drupal_mysql_database: drupal

# Additional arguments or options to pass to `drush site-install`.
drupal_site_install_extra_args: []

# Cron jobs are added to the root user's crontab. Keys include name (required),
# minute, hour, day, weekday, month, job (required), and state.
drupalvm_cron_jobs: []
  # - {
  #   name: "Drupal Cron",
  #   minute: "*/30",
  #   job: "drush -r {{ drupal_core_path }} core-cron"
  # }

# Drupal VM automatically creates a drush alias file in your ~/.drush folder if
# this variable is 'true'.
configure_local_drush_aliases: true

# Apache VirtualHosts. Add one for each site you are running inside the VM. For
# multisite deployments, you can point multiple servernames at one documentroot.
# View the geerlingguy.apache Ansible Role README for more options.
apache_vhosts:
  - servername: "{{ drupal_domain }}"
    documentroot: "{{ drupal_core_path }}"
    extra_parameters: |
          ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000{{ drupal_core_path }}"

  - servername: "adminer.drupalvm.dev"
    documentroot: "/opt/adminer"

  - servername: "xhprof.drupalvm.dev"
    documentroot: "/usr/share/php/xhprof_html"

  - servername: "pimpmylog.drupalvm.dev"
    documentroot: "/usr/share/php/pimpmylog"

apache_remove_default_vhost: true
apache_mods_enabled:
  - expires.load
  - ssl.load
  - rewrite.load

# Nginx hosts. Each site will get a server entry using the configuration defined
# here. Set the 'is_php' property for document roots that contain PHP apps like
# Drupal.
nginx_hosts:
  - server_name: "{{ drupal_domain }}"
    root: "{{ drupal_core_path }}"
    is_php: true

  - server_name: "adminer.drupalvm.dev"
    root: "/opt/adminer"
    is_php: true

  - server_name: "xhprof.drupalvm.dev"
    root: "/usr/share/php/xhprof_html"
    is_php: true

  - server_name: "pimpmylog.drupalvm.dev"
    root: "/usr/share/php/pimpmylog"
    is_php: true

nginx_remove_default_vhost: true

# MySQL Databases and users. If build_makefile: is true, first database will
# be used for the makefile-built site.
mysql_databases:
  - name: "{{ drupal_mysql_database }}"
    encoding: utf8
    collation: utf8_general_ci

mysql_users:
  - name: "{{ drupal_mysql_user }}"
    host: "%"
    password: "{{ drupal_mysql_password }}"
    priv: "{{ drupal_mysql_database }}.*:ALL"

# Comment out any extra utilities you don't want to install. If you don't want
# to install *any* extras, make set this value to an empty set, e.g. `[]`.
installed_extras:
  - adminer
  - drupalconsole
  - mailhog
  - memcached
  # - nodejs
  - pimpmylog
  # - redis
  # - ruby
  # - selenium
  # - solr
  - varnish
  - xdebug
  - xhprof

# Add any extra apt or yum packages you would like installed.
extra_packages:
  - unzip

# `nodejs` must be in installed_extras for this to work.
nodejs_version: "0.12"
nodejs_npm_global_packages: []

# `ruby` must be in installed_extras for this to work.
ruby_install_gems_user: "{{ vagrant_user }}"
ruby_install_gems: []

# You can configure almost anything else on the server in the rest of this file.
extra_security_enabled: false

drush_version: master
drush_keep_updated: true
drush_composer_cli_options: "--prefer-dist --no-interaction"

firewall_allowed_tcp_ports:
  - "22"
  - "25"
  - "80"
  - "81"
  - "443"
  - "4444"
  - "8025"
  - "8080"
  - "8443"
  - "8983"
firewall_log_dropped_packets: false

# PHP Configuration. Currently-supported versions: 5.5, 5.6, 7.0.
php_version: "5.6"
php_memory_limit: "192M"
php_display_errors: "On"
php_display_startup_errors: "On"
php_enable_php_fpm: true
php_realpath_cache_size: "1024K"
php_sendmail_path: "/usr/sbin/ssmtp -t"
php_opcache_enabled_in_ini: true
php_opcache_memory_consumption: "192"
php_opcache_max_accelerated_files: 4096
php_max_input_vars: "4000"

composer_path: /usr/bin/composer
composer_home_path: '/home/vagrant/.composer'
# composer_global_packages:
#   - { name: phpunit/phpunit, release: '@stable' }

# Run specified scripts after VM is provisioned. Path is relative to the
# `provisioning/playbook.yml` file.
post_provision_scripts: []
  # - "../examples/scripts/configure-solr.sh"

# MySQL Configuration.
mysql_root_password: root
mysql_slow_query_log_enabled: true
mysql_slow_query_time: 2
mysql_wait_timeout: 300
adminer_install_filename: index.php

# Varnish Configuration.
varnish_listen_port: "81"
varnish_default_vcl_template_path: templates/drupalvm.vcl.j2
varnish_default_backend_host: "127.0.0.1"
varnish_default_backend_port: "80"

# Pimp my Log settings.
pimpmylog_install_dir: /usr/share/php/pimpmylog
pimpmylog_grant_all_privs: true

# XDebug configuration. XDebug is disabled by default for better performance.
php_xdebug_default_enable: 0
php_xdebug_coverage_enable: 0
php_xdebug_cli_enable: 1
php_xdebug_remote_enable: 1
php_xdebug_remote_connect_back: 1
# Use PHPSTORM for PHPStorm, sublime.xdebug for Sublime Text.
php_xdebug_idekey: PHPSTORM
php_xdebug_max_nesting_level: 256

# Solr Configuration (if enabled above).
solr_version: "4.10.4"
solr_xms: "64M"
solr_xmx: "128M"

# Selenium configuration.
selenium_version: 2.46.0

# Other configuration.
known_hosts_path: ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

7.0.x is not a valid drupal version. Re-read the docs above that link in the drupal.make.yml and change it to "7.x"

Also, be sure to run `vagrant destroy` to remove all traces of the old instance. It could be that it isn't downloading a new copy, just using the D8 that it downloaded already.

Comment: Did my suggestion fix the problem? What was the solution?